# Two trips on a multiple-entry Schengen visa for a 30-day stay

Tags: schengen-visas

I have obtained a multiple-entry  Schengen visa for Italy from 9 August to 22 September, 30 day-stay. I'm going on a holiday to Rome from 10-16 August and returning back to Dubai.

Can I use the same visa to travel to Portugal from 12 to 16 September?

Total duration for both trips is less than 15 days.

Comment: Welcome to the site, cindy. We are a site that does not like to have several or even many questions with the same content, we close questions as duplicates when there is already a question with a good answer. As you can read in that question and answer, (see the link above) you can travel as planned, both on the same visa.

Comment: @dda, rolled back to an earlier version as you introduced an error.